# Load Image in DOM PDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

I am using dompdf to generate PDF in codeigniter, the pdf is being generated but the  image/logo is not picking. 
 I have tried to reference my logo in the following way in my view :

```
 <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/shwari.png">
```

Below is my controlller which I am usnig to load the  pdf :

```
class Dompdf_test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {


        $this->all_movements();
        // Get output html
        $html = $this->output->get_output();

        // Load library
        $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');

        // Convert to PDF
        $this->dompdf->load_html_file($html);

        $this->dompdf->render();
        $min = 1;
        $max = 1000;
        $name = rand($min, $max);
        $this->dompdf->stream($name . '.pdf');
    }

    public function all_movements() {


         $data['stocks'] = $this->inventory->getdepartmentalmovements();
        $data['meds'] = $this->inventory->get_meds();
        $this->load->view('dompdf', $data);


    }

}
```

What is the best way load the  image to the  pdf using DOMPdf?

Comment: If `$this->output->get_output()` returns a string then you should use `$dompdf->load_html()` instead of `$dompdf->load_html_file()`.

Comment: Since `base_url()` returns the site URL (with a trailing "/"?) it should work so long as `DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE` is set to `true`.

Comment: How does it appear within your document? Does it say image not found? Is the URL path correct when viewing it in the document?

Answer (score 1):

If DOMPDF cares about the URL then `<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/shwari.png">` should work but I would guess that you need a server path instead:

```
<img src="C:/I/Dont/Know/Your/Exact/Path/But/You/Should/Use/It/Here/assets/img/shwari.png">
```

In my app it would be

```
<img src="D:/web/sites/example.com/public_html/resources/images/my_image.png">
```